# Call a function in a cursor for loop

Tags: function, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I have created a procedure which finds some records with a missing date which needs to be populated.
I have written a cursor which uses a select statement to find these records and was going to use a for loop to update them.

There is an existing public function in the application that will return the date I need if I pass the ID of the record to it . My question is a syntax one really, how do I call this public function in a cursor for loop and pass the variable I need to it to get the date back then update the records that I have found in the cursor select statement.

The procedure I have written looks a bit like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRO_POPMISSINGDATE IS

CURSOR cur_FindMissingDate IS
 SELECT fieldID,
        field2,
        field3
 FROM table1
      table2
      table3
 WHERE CONDITION 1
       CONDITION 2
       CONDITION 3

BEGIN

FOR rec_cur_FindMissingDate IN cur_FindMissingDate
LOOP


BEGIN

        UPDATE TABLE2
        SET    missingdate = fnc_get_date(fieldID);

        WHERE  field2 = field4

        COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN

            dbms_output.put_line('Error updating record ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 250));
            ROLLBACK;
    END;
END LOOP;
END PRO_POPMISSINGDATE;
```

I am getting an ORA-00904 invalid identifier error in the update statement as it doesnt recognise
fieldID. I have evidently done something totally wrong here but I have hit a mental block, any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Does fieldID exist in TABLE2? I'm guessing it is the UPDATE statement for TABLE2 that is having the trouble -- you may need to add a FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
SET    missingdate = fnc_get_date(rec_cur_FindMissingDate.fieldID);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that has sorted it!