# Is there any way to use a function in a cursor for loop to insert value to table?

Tags: oracle, function, for-loop, plsql, cursor

Try to put a function (that populate sequence number) to a variable and use it in a cursor loop to insert it to each row of record, but error said invalid identifier to the v_refnr variable. `PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "V_REFNR": invalid identifier`.

The closest reference I found is this [1][Call a function in a cursor for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729362/call-a-function-in-a-cursor-for-loop)

My function has no parameter.  The select statement (contains other columns) I made in the cursor has no problem output the value. I proceed to use the for loop to iterate each record then insert a ref number to test if it works.

Here is my code I tried so far

```
Declare
 v_refnr number;
 cursor c_book IS
   --working select statement--
 r_book c_book%ROWTYPE

begin
  v_refnr := get_refnr; <-- function

  for r_book in c_book loop
  insert into some_tbl refnr
  values v_refnr;  
  end loop;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error insert record ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 250));
    ROLLBACK;
end;
```

If the above is the working code, it will insert value to the empty table.

Comment: I think it needs to fill all the columns and value to test it instead of only insert one value to test? I refer to this [insert row in a table using a cursor PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452545/insert-row-in-a-table-using-a-cursor-pl-sql)

Comment: Out of interest, why the `substr()` around `sqlerrm`? `dbms_output.put_line` can handle more than 250 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor loop for doing an Insert operation. Simply do an `INSERT INTO SELECT *`, it is far efficient than loops.

So, If you want to call the function each time, use it in the `select`.

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO some_tbl (refnr,col1,col2,col3)
     SELECT get_refnr,col1,col2,col3 from yoursourcetable; 
                                          --Your working select statement
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error insert record ' || substr(SQLERRM,1, 250));
 ROLLBACK;
END;
```

If you want to use the output of the function as a constant and only once then you may need a variable to store it and to it can used in the above select query in place of the function call.

Comment: I'd get the results from my source table and insert them into this `some_tbl`, but the columns of the `some_tbl` are different from the source table, so I don't think the above example would work to my case.

Comment: @Stu_Dent : It can, you should simply change the name of the columns accordingly

Comment: The first time I tried your suggestion doesn't populate the value to the `some_tbl`. My apology, let me try it again.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `insert ... values` is

```
insert into sometable (col1, col2, col3)
values (value1, value2, value3);
```

Your code is missing both sets of brackets.

There is a [PL/SQL-only variant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/INSERT-statement-extension.html) in which the `values` clause is replaced by a PL/SQL record:

```
insert into sometable (col1, col2, col3)
values plsqlrecord;
```

This does not have brackets around the values expression, but it needs to be a PL/SQL record, typically `sometable%rowtype`, which `v_refnr` is not, hence the error message.

Also, the [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) construction implicitly generates its own record, in this case the `r_book` in your loop, and your other `r_book` declared at the top is not used. A fixed version would therefore look something like this:

```
declare
    v_refnr number;

    cursor c_book is
        select col1, col2, col3 from book;
begin
    v_refnr := get_refnr;

    for r_book in c_book loop
        insert into some_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
        values (v_refnr, col2, col3);  
    end loop;
end;
```

though I would prefer to get rid of the cursor declaration by moving the query inline:

```
declare
    v_refnr number;
begin
    v_refnr := get_refnr;

    for r_book in (
        select col1, col2, col3 from book
    )
    loop
        insert into some_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
        values (v_refnr, col2, col3);  
    end loop;
end;
```

I've also improved the error handling by removing the `when others` exception handler that wasn't doing anything useful. The default handling of an unhandled exception is to print the error stack with line numbers and roll back the transaction to the start of the block, and attempting to code this yourself will never be as good because you lose the original line number and the block then appears to complete successfully when it actually didn't, not to mention there is no benefit in truncating the error message to 250 characters.

This just leaves three possible issues:

1. You only generate your number once at the top, and not once per row inserted. Perhaps that is the intention, but if not you should move the function call inside the loop.
2. If all `get_refnr()` does is generate a sequential number, Oracle already provides a method for doing that, called a [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html), or better still an [identity column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1).
3. If the only purpose of the loop is to insert rows from your `select` statement, as Kaushik Nayak pointed out you can do this in ordinary SQL using the `insert ... select` syntax with no need for any loops or variables etc, and it will be simpler and faster.